# Does change of address service with USPS work when request is made outside US?

Tags: usa, postal-system

I tried to file change of address on https://moversguide.usps.com/mgo/disclaimer after leaving US. After I filled out the information, when I clicked "Next", it doesn't move to the next webpage. Nor does it say anything wrong. Is that a technical problem, or because I am outside the US? Can anyone in or outside US verify that with me? Thanks.

---

UPDATE:

I just learned about using the console of my web browser to get some information when interacting on the webpage. After I typed in all the information, and clicked "Next", the console showed the following message

```
app.a7b49c3e.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: grecaptcha is not defined
    at app.a7b49c3e.js:1:90970
    at f (chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:73:16624)
    at Generator._invoke (chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:73:17950)
    at Generator.next (chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:73:17049)
    at r (chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1:22794)
    at s (chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1:22997)
    at chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1:23056
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1:22937
    at a.recaptchaTokenGet (app.a7b49c3e.js:1:91128)
(anonymous) @ app.a7b49c3e.js:1
f @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:73
(anonymous) @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:73
(anonymous) @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:73
r @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1
s @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1
(anonymous) @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1
(anonymous) @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1
recaptchaTokenGet @ app.a7b49c3e.js:1
(anonymous) @ app.a7b49c3e.js:1
f @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:73
(anonymous) @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:73
(anonymous) @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:73
r @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1
s @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1
(anonymous) @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1
(anonymous) @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1
recaptchaV3Validate @ app.a7b49c3e.js:1
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.59c5a8c1.js:1
f @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:73
(anonymous) @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:73
(anonymous) @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:73
r @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1
s @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1
Promise.then (async)
r @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1
s @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1
Promise.then (async)
r @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1
s @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1
(anonymous) @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1
(anonymous) @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:1
validate @ bootstrap.59c5a8c1.js:1
submit @ bootstrap.59c5a8c1.js:1
re @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:32
n @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:32
i._wrapper @ chunk-vendors.83ccc400.js:32
```

Also see the following screenshot:

[image]

I was wondering if it is a technical problem under GFW? What can I do about it?

With the help of a VPN, I could proceed to the next web pages, after clicking Next, but met a problem of not seeing a place where I could type in my credit card number in a webpage for payment, but only seeing where I could type in the security code of the card. Is that also because of GFW? What can I do about it?

Comment: Is your new address _outside_ the United States? The USPS form "new address" section doesn't contain entry fields for non-US countries or postal codes, which suggests that USPS will only forward mail to US addresses.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica the new address is still in US

Answer (score 1):

> Is that a technical problem, or because I am outside the US?

Technical problem. That's supposed to work from anywhere.

Comment: Thanks. Do you also encounter the same problem? In or outside US?

Comment: I was wondering what happen if you could fill out some information and click "Next"?